When using @ for an A Record does that completely change SLD?
When creating an A record, and I place an @ before the name.
If I understand this correctly, does this mean that I can change the name of the root domain.
In other words, if the domain is www.acme.com and I create an A record with @skippingrope that will change acme to skipping rope for that A record?

Webmasters site is a better fit for this.

No, it doesn't work like that. While the various zone editing tools can differ slightly, the convention is that only a lone @ is replaced with the zone origin, but when combined with any other text has no meaning – @abc would literally be a subdomain named "@abc". See examples at the end.
There is no special syntax for including out-of-zone records – in a text-based zone file you would simply write out the full name (with a standard trailing . to indicate that it's a "fully qualified" name), e.g. you could write www.skippingrope.com. A 1.2.3.4 – and then the server would reject it, because out-of-zone data is not allowed.
(Out-of-zone data is generally not allowed because requests for such data wouldn't be going to your nameserver in the first place. Your DNS records don't go into a single database of all domains; each domain has a dedicated database for its own records only.)
One important thing is that DNS has no special behavior or syntax regarding second-level domains – it treats all domain levels equally. So while it has a syntax (as above) to override the full name, you will not find any syntax to override e.g. just the 2nd-level name specifically. (Not that it would be useful anyway, given that out-of-zone data is not allowed.)
That also means that if your domain is "acme.com", then it is not correct to say that it is "www.acme.com" because those are two different things. (For example, if the domain really had been "www.acme.com" and you added a subdomain to that, it would be "www.www.acme.com"!)

For example, given an origin of example.com.:



Input
Becomes




@
example.com.


www
www.example.com.


ftp.www
ftp.www.example.com.


@asdf
@asdf.example.com.


@.asdf
@.asdf.example.com.


www.
www.


www.example.com.
www.example.com.


www.example.com
www.example.com.example.com.


www.acme.com.
www.acme.com.



Various web-based DNS management tools may interpret things slightly differently (e.g. some don't support @ and require you to leave the field blank), but text-based zone files are usually interpreted very consistently between different software.

Even though, a single @ to override the full name, it makes no difference because there is nothing to override it to begin with.
I suppose if you just want the domain without any name proceeding it, you'd use @.

That's basically what the answer says, yes. In web DNS panels you could just leave the subdomain field empty, but in text-based zone files that already had a different meaning, so they chose to use a @ for this purpose.
